# Capture my uibuttons event

Tags: ios7, delegates, view, xcode5

I have a big problem in my iphone/ipad ios7 app, I have a lot of controls based on UIView.
for example 
list in my view controller I'm adding list based on UIView, this list contains some controls subviews based on UIView, and this controls have a lot subviews (particulary uibuttons) too. And now I want get UIControlEventTouchUpInside action im my viewcontroller, how I can do that ? I Do delegate im my uibutton control but im my view controller I dont't have instance this button, so I can't use

```
myButton.delegate = self;
```

I Have just instance my SuperView.

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you use custom view class for your `UIView` which is you used for containing your button and other controls. In that custom class you can simply set the action for your controls.

**EDIT**

You can use the following method in your `UIButton`'s custom class:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self addTarget:self
             action:@selector(yourClickMethod:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)yourClickMethod:(UIButton *)infoButton {
    // Button action goes here
}
```

Comment: I have custom class which inherits from UIView, but I still don't have any idea

Comment: You have the button in the same class?

Comment: no, I'm adding another and another Views by using addSubview method, and later very deep I'm adding custom views inherits form UIButton